# Behavior of "ip addr add"

Tags: networking, server

Suppose I run the same `ip addr add x.x.x.x/xx brd ...` command several times in a row.

After the first time I would get `RTNETLINK answers: File exists` as output.

My question: does this leave the configuration in place, or is there a chance that the ip address goes down or is dropped for just a second before being added again?

I can't find any source code anywhere for this. Where could I find that?

Comment: No. The 1st command does the deed. The 2nd and subsequent commands don't mess with it - they fail, instead. The Unix/Linux method avoids making half changes.

Comment: Did you `dpkg -S $(type -p ip)` to find the package name, and `apt source` that package to get the source?

Comment: @waltinator Thanks. Good lord, looking back now, I don't know what came over me to even think that. Turns out the sourcecode isn't downloaded with deb-src, but I was able to determine it can be found here: https://github.com/shemminger/iproute2

Comment: It's C, which I can't read. Still, no "File exists" anywhere in the code. But yeah, it would not make sense to drop the ip and re-add it. The tool would be unusable if it worked like that.

Comment: That string isn't in the source, it's in a shared library. `grep` for "`error`". If you want to understand a program written in C, you must learn to "read C". Also run `man` on all the library calls.

Comment: Did you follow the "Information:" link to `https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/iproute2`?

Comment: I didn't see that link. Strange... Just read the documentation for adding and it mentions nothing about the behavior. Though it probably should be expected that it just works without changing anything http://www.policyrouting.org/iproute2.doc.html#ss9.2.1